# Handling all but one answer to a question being downvoted at the same time

Tags: discussion, downvotes, answers

Earlier today I posted a simple answer to: [SQL query to retrieve records that fall outside of a time range defined between two datetime fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085363/sql-query-to-retrieve-records-that-fall-outside-of-a-time-range-defined-between/24085493#24085493)

As soon as I did so about three or four other answers that were fairly similar popped up.  All were simple variants of showing the OP how to use DATEPART to get the hour variant.  All but one were immediately downvoted with no comment even though multiple people came up with the same logical solution.  I don't mind being downvoted when I am wrong or not useful.  I just got suspicious when every similar answer but one was downvoted with no comment.

Is this something common I need to ignore or is there a good way to handle it?

The OP hasn't responded to any answers or a comment asking what was wrong with the answers on the question.

Comment: I know little about SQL but from what I can tell there were 2 questions that did not solve the problem and 2 more had poor formatting. Both perfectly good reasons to downvote.

Comment: It doesn't look like anyone was targeted with downvotes in this case, and people are free to vote how they want outside of that. If someone found something wrong with all those answers there, that's up to them.

Comment: If all the answers were similar, and the voter thought they were wrong, it makes sense that he would downvote them all. If you're suspicious because one of them _wasn't_ downvoted, it could just have been timing -- maybe it appeared after the serial downvoter left the page.